# Android: Executing a program on adb shell

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb, porting

I have created an executable using **"include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)"** command in Android.mk .
My requirement is to execute the above generated executable over the abd shell.

**I tried:**

Below is my C-Code which is compiled using ndk-build command:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\n\nHello World\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Following is my **Android.mk** file contents:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloExecutable
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

When i execute the command **ndk-build** the following file is generated:

projectRoot->libs->**HelloExecutable**

My job is to execute the above generated file on the adb shell. So i first pushed the file onto the sdcard using the following command:

**adb push ~/projectRoot->libs->HelloExecutable /sdcard/**

Now i switch to adb shell using: **$adb shell** command(here i'm using an emulator).

Then i change the permissions as: **chmod 777 /sdcard/HelloExecutable**

Once the above command is executed, i get the executing permissions for my **HelloExecutable** file.

Then change the current working directory to sdcard. i.e. **cd /sdcard/**

Now when i try to execute the above file i get the following error:

```
# ./HelloExecutable
./HelloExecutable: permission denied
```

To perform the above i'm using an emulator. So can someone please tell the reason for the above error??

I kindly request the viewers to address the above problem. Waiting for your answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your SD card is mounted with `noexec` option. Try copying your file to another partition like /data and execute it from there.

Comment: how do  i check for noexec option??? And if it is enabled, then how do i disable it??

Comment: run "mount" command and see if SD card partition has "noexec" option listed.